# OpenFileDialog Multiselect problem

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog, multi-select

I have standart OpenFileDialog

```
var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
{
    DefaultExt = "mpo",
    Filter = "Image file |*.mpo",
    Multiselect = true,
    RestoreDirectory = true,
};
```

and when i try to use it to open several photos on "**fujifilm finepix real 3d w1**" photo camera it fires message box "**Cannot open multiple items from this location.  Try selecting a single item instead.**" Opening only 1 file is ok.

When i try to select photos from hard drive or other removable device everything is ok.

Anyone get the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you already found out that doing the same from another location doesn't make any problems, there is something with your camera.

As a workaround for your application you shouldn't open all the files directly on the device. Instead copy all selected items into a save location (a self-created folder below the temp folder) and open them from there.